# How to exlude automatically added files from nuget?

Tags: nuget

When you write `nuspec` file it is possible to use `files` tag and select some files with exclusion of some unwanted ones. However how I can exclude files that nuget adds **automatically**?

For example I have a project with with such file:

```
Schema\Configuration.xsd
```

nuget decides to add it to package and I cannot get rid of it (from the package).